# numpy loadtxt incrementally to preserve memory?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` array that is quite large, about a gigabyte or so.  It takes a long time to compute the values that go into the array, so once it's built, I serialize it with `np.savetxt`.  However, the conversion from an array of floats (which are 64bits each) to a file with strings representing those floats (which are 8bits*len(float_2_string_conversion) > 64bits) creates a file that is much larger than the original array.  I think that perhaps, `np.loadtxt` loads in all of the string content and then does a conversion to float all in one go.  Thus, the memory footprint of `np.loadtxt` is significantly larger than the original array.

In any case, I cannot load my array back into memory, because `np.loadtxt` is not very memory-polite.  Is there a convenient way to load a `numpy`-created csv back into memory that is not so memory hungry?

Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910591/numpy-loadtxt-function-seems-to-be-consuming-too-much-memory) seems to bring up this exact issue, but there does not seem to be any solution, merely an acknowledgement that this is a problem.

Comment: Save it in several files with an accepted size?

Comment: Do you need the file in txt format and with double floats? Otherwise use `np.save(file, arr.astype(np.float32))`

Comment: With `skiprows` and `max_rows` parameters you can read a subset of the rows of a `csv`.  But I don't think you can retain your place from a previous load.  Since the file format is simple, you could easily write your own reader - just read lines and split on delimiter.  It would be just as fast (may be better).  But for fast save/load `csv` is not the best.

Comment: Don't save an array as text file. Even the best optimized solutions are a lot slower and more memory consuming than saving it to a binary file (eg. np.save, or via h5py). If you want to load this array in another programming language like matlab, C++ or every language that can wrap c++ code, there are packages to directly load binary npy-files.

Comment: @max9111, I have managed to devise a solution to read in the lines a handful at a time (I posted it in the dupe).  I worry that if I had used a compressed solution, then this would not have been possible, and I would have been unable to recover the file at all without physically upgrading my computer hardware.  The load time was not prohibitive even for arrays that fill my RAM, and disk space is cheap and plentiful.  Memory-usage is the bottleneck here, and reading a text file line-by-line is hard to beat.

Comment: np.save doesn't produce a compressed file and is easily portable. It is simply a ascii header and a binary block, which makes it also quite straight forward to read in other modern programming languages.

Comment: @max9111 "and a binary block" but can it be read line-by-line?

Answer (score 1):

If you use np.load() you can set a memmap parameter. I have not used it cannot vouch for its performance.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html?highlight=memmap